# Kubernetes replicasets and database

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have a simple question on replicaSets or just replicas.
When having 3 Replicas as such:

> a pod containing 2 containers 1 x django application and a 1x
>   Postgresql database(linked to a volume)

How is the replication handled in terms of information? I mean how are the database synced to have the same information at all time? 
I would like to have a better grasp of the concept.

Thank you.

Comment: If each replica uses its own volume to store data, then you have to set up replication between those instances yourself. You cannot use the same volume for all replicas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wouldn't usually use ReplicaSets directly anymore, but assuming you mean in the context of a Deployment: each pod will be identical based on the template you provide. This means they will each get the same volume definition. What that does is mostly up to your choice of plugins and whatnot. There are volume providers that support multiple access (called ReadWriteMany mode). That said, Postgres does not support multiple processes using the same underlying files so that would not work in your particular case. What you would use instead is a StatefulSet, which lets you separately define volume templates so each pod gets a unique persistent volume.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What if I have a list of orders in a the database and have 4 containers on 2 different pods running the same application and depending of where the user requests the information the container must send the same consistent information to the user. How could I achieve that configuration? My understanding is that I would have to manage the database sync manually?

Comment: Kubernetes is not magic. All it's doing is connecting up some cloud storage devices. How would you run Postgres without Kubernetes?

Comment: Haha, Kubernetes is Magic when you're learning it as you dig deeper you demystify it. I would use google cloud databases.

Comment: Heh fair, but look into how you would run it on GCE using VMs and cloud disks and then design a similar layout using StatefulSets :)

Comment: Using your cloud provider's relational database service for storage and Kubernetes for compute is a totally valid combination.

Comment: Also that, my team uses RDS for everything we can.